# how to allocate non-cacheable physical memory in kernel?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

if want to allocate non-cacheable physical memory (DRAM) for usage in the driver,
(ie. don't want the data being cached into the CPU's data cache when
the data are accessed) how could I do this?

there are functions like kmalloc(), get_free_pages, vmalloc, etc,
but seems like that I can't specify if the data can be cached or not using these functions?
any suggestion on how to do it?

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In short there is no easy way to do this, it is very platform dependent.

 If you want a go at it read drivers/char/mem.c and Chapter 15 of the Linux Device Drivers 3rd Edition book.